# Scrapy can not see data inside del HTML tag

Tags: python, html, css, xpath, scrapy

I want to scrape the original and the discount price from this link:

https://www2.hm.com/hu_hu/productpage.0903062001.html

Both the span and the del class has weird class names, but I were able to find the discount price in Scrapy shell with the following:

response.css('span.price-value::text').get()

However I have no luck with the original which is inside a del tag:

```
<del class="BodyText-module--general__32l6J ProductPrice-module--priceValueOriginal__3U3Cz">6&nbsp;995 Ft</del>
```

I tried both xpath and css but Scrapy could not find this tag.

Comment: There is no such node as `del` in page source. You can scrape and parse `var productArticleDetails` from `script` node as JSON to get that value.  You need find `whitePrice` key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Original and discount price is embedded as JSON data in the page source itself

```
page_source_data = response.xpath('//div[@class= "tealiumProductviewtag productview parbase"]//text()')[0]
re.findall('product_original_price : \[(.*?)\],', page_source_data)
re.findall('product_list_price :  \["(.*?)\],', page_source_data)
```

This can be used to find the price

Comment: I am receiving an error when running the regular expressions:
expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: It worked, thank you, the issue was that .get() was missing from the page_source_data